# Ошибка со стороны сервера

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста где здесь ошибка :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `startpoke` (img,name,life,atk,def,exp,type) SELECT img,name,life,atk,def,exp,type FROM pokemon WHERE id=$_GET['startpoke']");
```

Мне выбивает такую ошибку

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:xampphtdocsstyleregister.php on line 47*

Comment: Прикол стал задавать вопросы более-менее правильно. Наверно, 21 все-таки наступил конец света... О_о

Comment: ну так да =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точка с запятой стоит?

`$_GET['startpoke']` - кавычки убери, либо используй такую конструкцию:

`".$_GET['startpoke']."`

P.S. все-таки копируешь из одной таблицы в другую?... Эх, для кого я третью нормальную форму объяснял. =(((

Comment: да это я здесь не поставил =) Но все равно не работает!

Comment: Покажи, пожалуйста, 46,47,48 строчки

Comment: mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (username,password,email,date,ip,startpoke) values('$username','$password','$email','$date','$ip','$startpoke')") or die(mysql_error()); это 46 , 47 - это вопрос, 48 - там пусто

Comment: а вы лучший=) оно работает =)

Comment: Нет, лучший кибергном и линг. Но я стремлюсь. ^^

Answer (score 0):

T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE насколько я помню - ошибка связанная с кавычками, т.е. например где-то незакрыта и т.д.